# IntelliJ terminal keymap not correct

Tags: intellij

In Android Studio, I use the terminal plugin and it worked fine. When I use `less`, I can use `Ctrl-F` and `Ctrl-B` to go back and forth one screen at a time.

On Intellij IDEA, however, this function is broken: when I hit `Ctrl-F` a search box will pop up in the terminal. `Ctrl-V` and `Alt-V` don't work either.

I have checked that in the Settings, the Override IDE Shortcuts option is ticked.

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and the lastest Intellij IDEA.